# Microsoft Excel time-based number increase

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

In regards to Excel 2013, is it possible to have a particular number constantly increasing on a time-based basis without me physically changing it ? For example, If I wanted the Number 50 to add 50 every hour; ex. 5:00 p.m. 50, 6:00 p.m. 100. 7:00 p.m. 150, etc.
Thanks.

Comment: Even if the file is closed?  ie. Should it update when re-opened?

Comment: Step back and explain the bigger picture. You can run a macro on a timer, but is that what you really need? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes, Even if the file is closed.

Comment: That could possibly be what im looking for. Thanks for the help

Comment: @MoietyDesign, the correct reference should be the ozgrid link which the bigresource (a spam aggregator site) question redirects too. And there too the question hasn't really been answered.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub TimeAddition()

Dim NowTime As Date
Dim Btime As Integer
Dim OffTime As Integer
Dim LR As Range
Dim IR As Range

'Set Ranges to a worksheet that will store
'your "static" variable information
'The reason you can't use a "Static" is they are reset
'whenever the workbook is closed

Set LR = Worksheets("Hidden").Range("A1")
Set IR = Worksheets("Hidden").Range("A2")

'Add your time interval between doing your task
dtime = Now() + TimeSerial(0, 0, 5)

'Set NowTime as the current time
NowTime = Now()

'If LR (Which is the last time the code ran, is empty, then this is the first
'run and set the last run time to the time now
If LR.Value = "" Then
LR.Value = Now()
End If

'If the current time is more than 15 seconds since the last time the code ran
'Then execute this section of the code. Your main task goes here
If NowTime >= (LR.Value + TimeSerial(0, 0, 15)) Then

Btime = Format((NowTime - LR.Value), "s") 'Workout the seconds between the times

OffTime = (Btime / 5) 'Divide the difference by 5, giving you an increment of 3 for every 5 seconds past

LR.Value = Now() 'Update LR (last time ran) to Now
IR.Value = IR.Value + OffTime 'Incremennt IR (your main value your interested in) by what was worked out
MsgBox "Updated IncVal, IncVal = " & IR.Value 'Output on message box (for testing)
End If

LR.Value = LR.Value 'Update Statics on sheet
IR.Value = IR.Value 'Update Statics On Sheet

Application.OnTime dtime, "TimeAddition" 'Schedule next run


End Sub
```

How this works is explained in the comments in the code. Remember to hide the "Hidden" sheet. I use this sort of method a lot and it never fails me. It wont "Update" when the workbook is closed, but it will work out how much time has elapsed once the workbook is reopened and update accordingly

Please edit to suit your needs!